# How to make the prompt like this image(link)?

Tags: prompt

http://min.us/muKpIB16z

Is that zsh?
Could somebody share the PS1 code to everyone :P?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `__git_ps1`:

```
PS1='\u@\h:\w$(__git_ps1)\$ '
```

Comment: Note: `__git_ps1` is sometimes not available on OS X distributions of git, but you can google it and download separately.

Answer (score 1):

it's probably a theme from [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), git support is part of a lot of them. see their [theme gallery](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes) for lots of examples…